# Ошибка UnicodeDecodeError при открытии файла

Tags: python, файлы, utf-8, unicode

При попытке открыть текстовый файл `docx` вылетает ошибка. Такое же происходит и с другими файлами. Я в основном работаю на маке, но решил проверить и на винде, там всё работает. Кто знает в чём проблема и как её решить, напишите пожалуйста)

```
try:
    with open('/Users/pavel/Desktop/python_test1/11.docx', 'r') as f:
    print(f.read())

except FileNotFoundError:
    print("Файл не найден!")
```

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/pavel/PycharmProjects/how_to_work_with_files/venv/file_work.py", line 88, in <module>
    print(f.read())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd2 in position 16: invalid continuation byte```
````

Comment: помощью модуля Python-Docx

Comment: Вкратце: docx - это не текстовый файл (грубо говоря - это архив с xml и другими файлами), просто через open текст из него не прочитать. Нужно использовать дополнительные библиотеки, тот же python-docx, например.